# Laravel - How to pass variable from other function in same controller

Tags: json, laravel, api, laravel-api

I am a beginner of laravel. Recently I am involving in a small project and having some issue. I
am making laravel api to update my member information. As example in the code below, I have two functions in my one controller which is **getMember** and **update** But for my **update** function, I have no idea how to pass the variable in json from one function to another. I want to get the variable '2' from my **getMember** function and pass it to **update** function in order to update member.

```
    public function getMember(Request $request)
    {
        return response()->json([

            'id'=> 2
    ]);
    }


    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $member = $this->getMember($request);

        $member = Member::find($member->id);


        if($request->member_name !=null) {
         $member->update([
            'member_name'=> $request->member_name
        ]);

    }

return response()->json(['message'=>'Member has been updated.'
    ],200);
}
```

Really need help from you all. Any comments are appreciated thanks.

Comment: Its a really strange way of handeling things. Normally you've got the member id in the view, and pass it to the action using a route parameter or post parameter

Comment: If it's an API, why do you get the member that way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't what you want to achieve by just return it from function don't return the response back

```
public function getMember(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->id;
    }
```

Comment: true, but still a strange way of getting the member id :-)

Comment: @Ali Alizadeh , Thanks for reply.